# Is that possible to play use ClippingMediaSource to clip a collection of ConcatenatingMediaSource?

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to loop a video (mp4) for certain period of Time and if they don't fit perfectly, it will play partially within the time frame. I play around with two videos first.

I use `ConcatenatingMediaSource` with two mp4 and then wrap that with `ClippingMediaSource`.

```
  val baseMediaSource1 = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(...).createMediaSource(videoUrl)
  val baseMediaSource2 = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(...).createMediaSource(videoUrl)

  val concat = ConcatenatingMediaSource(true, baseMediaSource1, baseMediaSource2)
  mediaSource = ClippingMediaSource(concat, <duration for 10seconds>)
```

I expect it to play but the logcat actually said

> com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ClippingMediaSource$IllegalClippingException:
>   Illegal clipping: invalid period count

BTW, I tried `ClippingMediaSource(LoopingMedaiSource(...), ...)` and it gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on Exoplayer github issues page and the answer, for now, is No. It does not support the operation. The best is to use external mechanism to send a message via handler after period of time reached. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/6234